STM32L476 ADC always displaying the max value 4095 every conversion
I am implementing an ADC on an STM32L476 to read a voltage value from a GPIO pin. I am not using HAL for efficiency reasons so I am doing it bare metal. However, every time I read a conversion I get the maximum value, 4095, no matter the input voltage into the GPIO pin. I searched all over the web for any references but there are not many resources for ADCs in the L4 series.
/*
 * adc.c
 */

#include "adc.h"

//USES ADC1

void adc_init(){
    RCC->AHB2ENR |= RCC_AHB2ENR_ADCEN; //enables ADC clock
    RCC->CCIPR   &= ~( RCC_CCIPR_ADCSEL ); //enables peripheral clock
    RCC->CCIPR   |=  ( 3 << RCC_CCIPR_ADCSEL_Pos ); //Sets ADC clock to system clock
    ADC1->CR    &= ~( ADC_CR_DEEPPWD );//makes sure ADC isn't in deep power down mode
    ADC1->CR |= ADC_CR_ADVREGEN; //enables ADC voltage regulator
    nop(10000); //waits a bit
    ADC1->CR &= ~(ADC_CR_ADCALDIF); //Sets it to single ended mode
    ADC1->CR |= ADC_CR_ADCAL; //Calibrates ADC
    while ((ADC1->CR & ADC_CR_ADCAL) != 0) { } //Waits until ADC is calibrated

}

void adc_enable(){
    ADC1->ISR |= ADC_ISR_ADRDY; // Set before enabling ADC
    ADC1->CR |= ADC_CR_ADEN; //Enables ADC
    while ((ADC1->ISR & ADC_ISR_ADRDY) == 0) { } //Waits until ADRDY is reset
}
void adc_configGPIO(){
    RCC->AHB2ENR |= RCC_AHB2ENR_GPIOCEN; //enables GPIO C
    while (GPIOC->OTYPER == 0xFFFFFFFF); //Waits until its done enabling

    GPIOC->OTYPER       &= ~( GPIO_OTYPER_OT0 ); //Reset C0 pin
    GPIOC->PUPDR        &= ~( GPIO_OSPEEDR_OSPEED0 ); //Reset C0 pin
    GPIOC->OSPEEDR      &= ~( GPIO_PUPDR_PUPD0 ); //Reset C0 pin
    GPIOC->MODER        &= ~( GPIO_MODER_MODE0 ); //Reset C0 pin
    GPIOC->ASCR         |=  ( GPIO_ASCR_ASC0 ); //Connects analog switch to ADC channel for C0
    GPIOC->MODER        |=  ( 0x3 << GPIO_MODER_MODE0_Pos ); //Sets mode to analog
}


void adc_setChannel(){
    //leave sampling time at default
    ADC1->SQR1 &= ~( ADC_SQR1_L ); //Sets number of channels in the sequence of 1
    ADC1->SQR1 &= ~(ADC_SQR1_SQ1); //Resets the sequence
    ADC1->SQR1 |= (1 << ADC_SQR1_SQ1_Pos); //Sets the sequence to just channel 1 (PIN C0)
    ADC1->SMPR1 &= ~( ADC_SMPR1_SMP1 ); //Resets the sampling time of channel 1
    ADC1->SMPR1 |=  ( 0x7 << ADC_SMPR1_SMP1_Pos ); //Sets the sampling time to max: 640.5 cycles per sample
}

// Perform a single ADC conversion.
// (Assumes that there is only one channel per sequence)
uint16_t adc_singleConversion() {
  // Start the ADC conversion.
  ADC1->CR  |=  ( ADC_CR_ADSTART );
  // Wait for the 'End Of Conversion' flag.
  while ( !( ADC1->ISR & ADC_ISR_EOC ) ) {};
  // Read the converted value (this also clears the EOC flag).
  uint16_t adc_val = ADC1->DR;
  // Wait for the 'End Of Sequence' flag and clear it.
  while ( !( ADC1->ISR & ADC_ISR_EOS ) ) {};
  ADC1->ISR |=  ( ADC_ISR_EOS );
  // Return the ADC value.
  return adc_val;
}


Here is the main program
nop() delays by an amount of microseconds
printMsg() prints a uart message so I can read it
init_platform() handles other things, which is why I am resetting the GPIO pins completely before using it.
void branch_main(){
    //test ADC
    adc_init();

    adc_enable();

    adc_configGPIO();

    adc_setConstantGPIOValue();

    adc_setChannel();

    while(1){
        printMsg("ADC value: %d \r\n", adc_singleConversion());

        nop(1000000);
    }
}

int main() {
    init_platform();
    branch_main();
}

I tried using the internal channels such as VREFINT and VBAT but even on those channels I am repeatedly getting a maximum value of 4095 and nothing else. This leads me to believe that I am missing some register settings for the ADC or anything that the ADC depends on rather than an issue with the GPIO pin.
Any idea of what went wrong?

while (GPIOC->OTYPER == 0xFFFFFFFF); //Waits until its done enabling what was this line supposed to be? It almost certainly does nothing at all.

uint16_t adc_val = ADC1->DR; this could be the problem. DR is defined as __IO uint32_t DR; (where __IO is volatile) . Which means, you read uint32_t, then cast it to uint16_t and save that into the variable. But every time you read, there is a 32-bit read instruction first. This could be irrelevant, but I had problems because of this before. Try uint16_t adc_val = *(uint16_t*)&ADC1->DR; to force specifically 16-bit read.

What hardware is this, your own or a "known good" board such as Nucleo or Disco? How is VREF+ connected (check physically, think of bad solder joints or shorts if this is your hardware)? How are all other VSS and VDD pins (including the analog ones) connected?

@wek It's our own board. The VREF+ is decoupled and I am trying to use the internal reference voltage. However, it just came to my attention that I need to set the ENVR bit in the VREFBUF_CSR register to enable the internal voltage reference. I will try that once I have access to the board again.
